# Excel VB script to compare values and copy data

Tags: excel, copy, compare, vba

My spreadsheet is setup as follows:

Sheet 1:
Column A: Unique alpha numeric values starting from cell A2
Column B - Alpha numeric values (non-unique)

Sheet 2:
Column A: Unique alpha numeric values starting from cell A2
column B: Empty

I want a function to compare between `Sheet1.ColumnA` and `Sheet2.ColumnA`, and when a match is found, copy the data from `Sheet1.ColumnB` to `Sheet2.ColumnB`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is about helping you develop your knowledge and skills. It is not a free coding service although the help may be in the form of a routine if the answerer thinks that is the best way of helping. But you must demonstrate that you have tried to solve your own problem before seeking help.

Answer (score 1):

this is done through `VLOOKUP()`.
In this case you should put in your sheet2 column B the following function (write in B2 and then drag it to the end):

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE),"")`

`VLOOKUP()` is a very powerful function for all these kind of problems which a lot of "normal" Excel users have each day.

The `IFERROR()` Is used for those cases where the unique ID in sheet2 cannot be found in the table on sheet1.